# In the Library of Count Dracula

Tags: puzzle, word-problem

Am thinking about this question from the book Analysis $1$ by Herbert Amann and Joachim Escher:

*In the library of Count Dracula no two books contain exactly the same number of
words. The number of books is greater than the total number of words in all the books.
These statements suffice to determine the content of at least one book in Count Dracula’s
library. What is in this book?*

My reasoning: If there is a total of $n$ words in all books, then there can be at most $n$ different books (since each book must have a different number of words). So how can there be more books than the total number of words in all books?

Am assuming there are no books with $0$ words.

Comment: Maybe the point is that there must be a book with no words.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes thats what am starting to believe.

Comment: @Manlio This question is in the first chapter so I don't think we are dealing with infinity yet.

Comment: Maybe I'm slow but doesn't that imply there can be at most two books? One book with no words and one book with one word? If I'm not mistaken adding a book then would increase the book counter by 1 but the word counter by at least 2, so there'd always be more (or at least as many) words than books.

Comment: The same number of words is not the same set of words Book 1 can be "Hello there" and Book 2 can be "Hello, how are you?" 2+4 words, but overall 5 words.

Comment: @AsafKaragila True, but still you cannot have more books than the the total number of words in all books if you assume no books with $0$ words.

Comment: I think "word" means instance, not unique instance.  So a book containing "hello hello" = $2$ words, not $1$ word.  I mean, that's how "word count" usually works, right?  Assuming my convention, then (1) there is a book with no word, and (2) there may or may not be another book with $1$ word, and (3) that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was reading this in Amann's Analysis 1 last night (I know, strange bedtime reading). I thought I would flesh out my take on it since the question is still unanswered (even if the comments state the solution).

You are forced to assume that one book has only blank pages:

Let $n$ be the number of books and $x_i$ the number of words in the $i$-th book. I interpret *"The number of books is greater than the total number of words in all the books"* as
$$
x_1 + \cdots + x_n < n
$$
If $x_i > 0$ for all $i$ you get
$$
  x_1 + \cdots + x_n \geq 1 + \cdots + 1 = n
$$
which contradicts the previous inequality. So at least one of the $x_i$ has to be $0$.

Now, if you bring in the additional assumption $x_i\neq x_j$ for $i\neq j$, you can prove that the only options are $n=1, x_1=0$, or $n=2, x_1 = 0, x_2=1$:

You have $n$ non-negative numbers $x_1,\dots, x_n$ which are all different. Also $x_i < n$ for all $i$ otherwise the sum would be $\geq n$. Since there are only $n$ integers between $0$ and $n-1$, you have, up to a relabeling of the books, $x_i = i - 1$. But then
$$
  x_1 + \cdots + x_n = 0 + 1 + \cdots + (n-1) = \frac{(n-1)n}{2}< n
$$
which reduces to
$$
  n(n - 3) < 0
$$
and the only solutions for $n$ an integer are $n = 1$ and $n = 2$.

Comment: Thats a boring library! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Probably should be "which reduces to $n-3 < 0$"

Comment: I am curious about this problem. You seem to solve the problem ("So at least one of the $x_i$ has to be 0") without using "In the library of Count Dracula no two books contain exactly the same number of words." Is that correct? When you later use "In the library of Count Dracula no two books contain exactly the same number of words" you appear to then derive the possible number of books in the library (which was not asked for be AE). Is that also correct?

Comment: BTW, I am just starting AE. Is it worthwhile for someone who didn't love that Baby Rudin didn't seem to give a lot of intuition?

Comment: @EE18 yes that's correct, at least in my interpretation of the text of the problem, you only need the assumption "no two books contain exactly the same number of words" to find how many books there are. As for books advice, it depends. If you are just looking for a first course in real analysis I would go with Bartle and Sherbert, Introduction to Real Analysis

Comment: Thanks for your help! Re books: I have done Spivak’s Calculus (not on manifolds), so I have that background. Would AE be OK given that background? The only thing I worry about is that there is no “ecosystem” of solutions if I get stuck.

Comment: It's probably enough for the first volume. For the second you'll need more familiarity with linear algebra (vector spaces etc.., up to the Jordan canonical form). You need linear algebra for the first volume also, but not as much. AE is very clear and general, but it does skip steps later on, and in terms of intuitive explanations I would say it's similar to Rudin