# The Count Dracula Library

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*In the library of Count Dracula no two books contain exactly the same number of words. The number of books is greater than the total number of words in all the books. These statements suffice to determine the content of at least one book in Count Dracula’s library. What is in this book?*

This question has already been answered in [In the Library of Count Dracula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3661304/in-the-library-of-count-dracula).

However, I think the assumption “*no two books contain exactly the same number of word*” is superfluous. I mean that removing this assumption would not affect the final answer. Do I miss a point?

Comment: Yes you are right. But the second assumption gives us the only two possible cases about the values of n that are outlined in the answer to the question you have linked.

Comment: Yes, but the exercise is not about the number of books. That’s why I asked this question

Comment: @Moo that was already linked by the OP.  The punchline is that the OP is correct that the first condition is superfluous.  The only benefit of keeping that first condition is that it tells us that there can be only one empty book and there can not be any books with more than one word.  Without the first condition it is possible that Dracula has a thousand copies of the empty book and one book with a thousand words while still satisfying the second condition.  Either way, the empty book must be in his collection at least once (*exactly once if first condition is kept*)

Comment: @JMoravitz - it also tells us that the Count can have at most two books, as to have more would mean multiple books with word count $1$. Apparently he is more into counting than reading.